# Cannot mount shared NAS directory with ownCloud

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, owncloud

I managed to run `ownCloud` on my RaspberryPi 2 on Raspbian. Now I am trying to move the data directory to my NAS.

I already shared a folder on my NAS with `CIFS` and mounted the folder.
This allows me to access the shared directory via the command line and manipulate entries. So that works. However, when opening ownCloud in my browser, I get the following error message:

> Data directory (/home/pi/Cloud/storage) is readable by other users
>
> Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed by other users.

So I tried to adjust the permissions in the `/etc/fstab` file, where I mounted the shared directory. This also worked out, but changes the owner from `www-data` to `pi`. With the result that ownCloud does not run at all, since the data directory has to be owned by `www-data`.

I mounted the shared folder by adding the following line to the `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//<NAS-IP>/<sharedFolder> /home/pi/Cloud/storage cifs username=<my username>,password=<my password>,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,dir_mode=770,file_mode=770,umask=0007 0 0
```

Which results in these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi    pi    4096 Sep  2  23:15 storage
```

So the problem is that the data directory can be read by all users, but when I restrict the permissions, it is not owned by `www-data` anymore.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? It seems that I am so close to have ownCloud running, but I can't figure out this last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turned out that the permissions on the NAS were not set correctly. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307754/166230) pointed me in the right direction.

The problem was, that I created the shared folder on the NAS as `admin` user via the GUI. I solved the problem by deleting that folder and **recreating it via SSH as the user that I also specified in the `/etc/fstab` file**.

I also adjusted my `/etc/fstab` file to look like this:

```
//<NAS-IP>/<sharedFolder> /home/pi/Cloud/storage cifs username=<my username>,password=<my password>,uid=www-data,gid=www-data 0 0
```

After that I still received an error message about a missing `.ocdata` file which I solved by simply creating an empty file with that name.

Answer (score 0):

For the next person who runs into this issue like I did. 
umask, fmask and dmask did not work for me. 
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I had to add the **dir_mode=0770** option to my fstab. I am using a windows share from a 2012 server as my base storage. I was receiving the same message

```
"Data directory (/home/pi/Cloud/storage) is readable by other users
Please change the permissions to 0770 so that the directory cannot be listed 
by other users."
```